# Is it Possible to access the sqlite3 db of one application from other in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using android build target vendor version 2.2.

I want to access/read sqlite3 database file of an application A from an application B. Is it possible to do so? because i don't want to import that DB file of apps A in Apps B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no, not directly, although it is possible to expose the data from application A via a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) and consume it from application B in a similar fashion.

[See here for more on `ContentProvider`s](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, assuming that apps A and B are both yours, it might well be possible using the [sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) (and possibly [sharedUserLabel](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uidlabel)) attributes in your AndroidManifest.xml - if both apps are running under the same UID, you should be able to read app A's files from app B.  I've never done it myself, but [here](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2009/06/controlling-application-separation.html) and [here](http://androidboss.com/androids-shareduserid/) look like places to learn the ins and outs of that method.